# Unique arrays in a multidimensional array

Tags: perl, grep, unique, uniq

I have a multidimensional array and I'm looking for a way to get only unique elements in the array.

```
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use List::Util 'shuffle';
#use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

my @array = shuffle (
    [4, 10],
    [5, 6],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2]
);

sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
};
my @unique = uniq(@array); 
foreach (@unique) {say "@$_";};
```

And this doesn't work. It seems like each array in a multidimensional array is a different reference.

I  tried to use uniq from MoreUtils but it also doesn't work.

Please help.

P/s: I'm looking for a way to produce [4, 10] [5, 6] [1, 2].

Comment: How does it "not work"? What output are you expecting? Do you mean the unique elements of the set of all elements of all arrays? So the output would be one array containing `[4, 10, 5, 6, 1, 2]`? Or do you mean the unique arrays so the output would be an array of arrays containing `[4, 10]`. `[5, 6]`, and `[1,2]`? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Sorry terdon, I forgot to add the expected output. It's the later that I want. [4, 10], [5, 6], and [1,2]. It looks like the underlying cause is because they're inherently different references so despite [1, 2] are the same but they're actually different.

Comment: Yes, exactly: the keys of your `%seen` hash are references, things like `ARRAY(0x5605c4905688)`.

Comment: What should happen if an array has the same elements in different order? Should `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]` be counted separately or considered a match?

Comment: Yes, terdon. I never thought about this issue until now and it is really worth looking into. Perl is really strange in this since I see that other languages don't behave like Perl.

Answer (score 3):

You have to reference both array values in your `%seen` hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use List::Util 'shuffle';


my @array = shuffle (
    [4, 10],
    [5, 6],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2]
);

sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_->[0]}{$_->[1]}++, @_;
};
my @unique = uniq(@array); 
foreach (@unique) {say "@$_";};
```

Instead of a nested hash, you could stringify the two elements like so:

```
grep !$seen{"$_->[0],$_->[1]"}++, @_;
```

For the general case of an array of arbitrary data structures you can serialize the elements. This example uses `Storable::freeze` for serialization. `$Storable::canonical` needs to be set to true to allow for comparison of data structures. See [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/Storable#CANONICAL-REPRESENTATION).
As @Ikegami points out, this will still cause problems with float values...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use List::Util 'shuffle';
use Data::Dumper;
use Storable qw/freeze/;
#use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

my @array = shuffle (
    [4, 10],
    [5, 6],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,{foo=>'bar'}],
    [1,2,{foo=>'bar'}],
    [1,2,{foo=>'baz'}],
);

sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    local $Storable::canonical = 1;
    grep !$seen{freeze( $_ )}++, @_;
};
my @unique = uniq(@array); 
say Dumper \@unique;
```

Comment: I understand it now. Thank you, clamp. Is there any other way that we can work around this? This is a 2D array but if it's 3D then it's really cumbersome.

Comment: @Tiendu, No, there's no way to work around checking every cell of the item if you want to check every cell of the item.

Comment: Note that this assumes all arrays will have exactly 2 elements. Dunno if that's a problem.

Comment: @ikegami Understood. Most of the time, I use 2D array. If there's really no workaround for it, any suggestions for a different data structure?

Comment: @Tiendu that will depend entirely on what you want to do. But if the objective is about having unique elements, you should probably look into perl's hashes instead.

Comment: If it‘s n dimensions you can still stringify to 1-dimensional hash keys.

Comment: @terdon We ARE using hashes to enforce lack of duplication.

Comment: @terdon Re "*Note that this assumes all arrays will have exactly 2 elements*", The specific implementation, yes, but the concept works for larger arrays. The bigger assumption is that the values of the array are integers or strings that don't contain `,`.

Comment: @Tiendu Re "*any suggestions for a different data structure?*", Changing the data structure doesn't remove the need to check every value in the structure. You'd still need to generate the same key string.

Comment: @ikegami _The bigger assumption is that the values of the array are integers or strings that don't contain_ `,` . I added a version for the general case, serializing elements.

Comment: I doubt that `freeze` guarantees that it always produces the same output for the same input. Specifically, I would expect identical hashes to be stored differently. /// And it still doesn't handle floating point number well. One usually wants to compare floating point numbers with some amount of tolerance to account for lack of precision.

Comment: @ikegami thank you for clarifying, will remove the part.

Comment: @ikegami according to the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/Storable#CANONICAL-REPRESENTATION) setting `$Storable::canonical = 1;` _allows you to compare data structures by comparing their frozen representations_

Comment: I hadn't seen you use that. I would have placed `local $Storable::canonical = 1;` in `uniq`. That does address the hash issue. But not the float issue.